# VC++: Build a user interface form in the DLL and let it run in background

Tags: forms, user-interface, visual-c++, dll

I develop a DLL within VS C++ 2010 which creates the shared data for other applications.

Now I want to create a user interface class within this dll, so that every time if the DLL is loaded, this user interface will be shown to display the states and values of shared data.

The problem is, every time I invoke the ui window, it comes out and freezes.

So my question is, how can I make this ui class running completely in a separate thread without freezing itself?

I have googled around and found some concepts eg. with BackgroundWorker. But I can't find some useful examples.

If anyone can help, I am really thankful for that.

Comment: Displaying UI on a worker thread has many problems, this is just a small one.  It "freezes" because the thread isn't running a dispatcher loop, Application::Run().   The much bigger unsolvable problems are the Z-order of the windows and [this nasty issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  Don't do it.

Comment: Your description is quite vague. Please provide more info what is happening with your windows.

Comment: The window should start if the dll is loaded. And it should functional to react on button clicks.